# How to resolve fmt.Print not work in android？

Tags: android, ios, go, stdout, cgo

I try to use golang to export android and iOS library. Try to print Hello world. I found fmt.Print method work in iOS but not in android. print method work in android not in iOS. Why？ How to resolve it.

Resolve print log in both android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the standard **output** and **error streams** are typically redirected to the Android logging system. To print log messages in Android, you should use the `log` package instead of `fmt`. The `log` package provides functions specifically designed for logging in the Android environment. You can use `log.Print` or `log.Println` to print log messages.

if you want to use `log` package like `fmt` . you can remove the time stamp from log message print fuction

```
logger := log.New(os.Stdout, "", 0) // Create a new logger with an empty prefix and no flags
logger.Print("I'm Sk Shahriar Ahmed Raka") // Print log message without timestamp
```